# Calling functions from different ruby files in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I m working in rails.i want to call a function(show) of class "twitter" in searcht1 which is in "lib"  within a same directory from rake task.

```
lib/task/search.rake:                                                                                                           

require_relative "lib/Searcht1"      
  namespace :Searcht do
   task :search => :environment do
     obj=Twitter.new
     obj.show
   end  
  end
```

and the class inside the "searcht1.rb" is like this

```
class Twitter
 def show
  "anylogic"
 end
end
```

but it is not calling that function.and i m not getting any result. 
 greatly aprreciate any help

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: How about `require_relative "../lib/searcht1"` ? You seem to have some typos there, too, e.g. `searcht1` vs. `seracht1` and `Twitter` vs. `twitter`, but maybe those are just from typing in the question too quickly...

Comment: @p11y: not working "../lib/searcht1" and about those typos. yeah those were my typing error in the question

Comment: which type of app do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit outdated, but I had the problem in my rails5 app and this is how I keep my tasks clean :)

Please make a subdir **searchdir** in *lib/task**s*** => **lib/tasks/searchdir** and put your referenced file **searcht1.rb** in there.
Now you can reference it in your rake file.

Please keep in mind: it is run from the referenced file.

```
# in lib/tasks/search.rake                                                                                                           

namespace :Searcht do
 task :search => :environment do
   require_relative "searchdir/searcht1"      
 end  
end
```

make your code run here:

```
# in lib/tasks/searchdir/searcht1.rb
class Twitter
  def show
    "anylogic"
  end
end

obj=Twitter.new
obj.show
```